# How to convert this part of web.xml to Java configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, configuration, web.xml

i want to convert this:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SassCompiler</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.darrinholst.sass_java.SassCompilingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SassCompiler</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

in web.xml into **exactly the same** thing in Java configuration, what should i do?

It's pure spring mvc project, no boot or something

Comment: pure spring project or spring-boot project ?

Comment: What have you tried and what were the results?

Comment: pure spring mvc, no boot or something

Comment: i didn't try anyting cause i had no idea how to solve this